# Failed to resolve "System.Void Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement::set_StyleClass reference from "Xamarin.Forms.Core, Version=2.0.0.0,

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

Failed to resolve "System.Void Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement::set_StyleClass(System.Collections.Generic.IList`1)" reference from "Xamarin.Forms.Core, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"

I am getting this error when I try to run application in iPad.
I am not getting what is the problem, app is running perfectly in IOS simulator

Comment: It's possible Xamarin only integrates .NET 2.0 classes on the target instead of the .NET 3.5 ones that include the "System.Collections.Generic" things.

Comment: Can't it be made to use .NET 3.5 or 4.0 on iPad too? This anyway is a bug of Xamarin itself.

Comment: Try disabling the linker and see if it works then. https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/linker/

Comment: It's also recommended to ensure your Xamarin.Forms packages are updated to the latest stable version and that they do not differ in your `Core` project vs. your `iOS` project. Make sure they are on the same version.